# Require file including variable

Tags: php, variables, require, require-once

I am currently using the following code to include a file in my webpage:

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/include/file.php';
```

However, I have now edited my system so I input the URL into a data file in the root which makes other parts of my site function and allows me to use different directories.

In short, I am using a splash page on a website, where the root is now /directory rather than in the root, thus the URL in my data file is http://www.domain.com/directory.

So, what I need to work out is how to point this line at the directory *using the variable from the data file which contains the URL*

So `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` becomes irrelevant because I need to grab the data from the variable in the data file which is NOT in the root anymore.

It needs to be something like:

```
require_once (variable from file a few directories back) + absolute path to file;
```

I want this line of code to be future-proof too, if I need to build a site using a different directory then the root.

I hope that makes sense!

Comment: The only thing that makes sense is to have two different variables; Separate your base url settings and local document root.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  Is file.php now in /directory/include/file.php, or is it still at /include/file.php?  Can you give us some real examples of your current directory structure, where file.php is, and what this config variable contains?

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I control my entire system from one php file, and I'd like to keep it that way. I know it's possible to use PHP to make this possible - I just need someone who knows PHP back-to-front to help me with this code! :)

Comment: Thanks for your response jwegner, yes the new path is /directory/include/file.php. The variable I need to include is located in /directory. The variable contains the URL to the data file containing the variable i.e $url = 'http://www.domain.com/directory' Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `SITE_ROOT` and use that instead. That way, it will work with any directory change.

```
define('SITE_BASE', '/directory/');
define('SITE_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . SITE_BASE);
```

You can then use `SITE_BASE` for creating your URIs:

```
<a href="<?php echo SITE_BASE ?>subdir/">link</a>
```

and `SITE_ROOT` for accessing files on the system:

```
require_once SITE_ROOT . 'include/file.php';
```

Comment: That sounds like the perfect solution! Where would I contain the data for SITE_ROOT? Many many thanks!

Comment: It would need to be one of the first lines of code to run on every page. So however that works best for your particular application.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help. If this is the best answer, please click the checkmark :)

Comment: It works, but I need to be able to use the variable in /directory/data.php which contains the absolute URL to it (http://www.domain.com/directory/data.php). I could add your code to the data.php file and it would solve my issue, but then I'd have to change about 100 lines of other code which points towards the variable. It's just this one require_once line that isn't working. Thanks again for your help, but if you know how I could achieve this I would very much appreciate your help. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered setting `include_path` in your `php.ini` file? For instance, my own `php.ini` file has `include_path = ".:/path/to/web/root"`, which allows me to not worry about where my files are when including them.

In your case, you would want to set it to `include_path = ".:/path/to/web/root/directory"`. If you don't know the path to the web root, just run `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` to find it.

This solution is "future-proof", as you only need to change that `php.ini` value and everything falls into place.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Kolink. I am not using a php.ini file. I'm not a PHP expert just yet :( I am using a single .php file to control all my pages. That does sound like it would solve my issue though. I will look into this further. Thank you very much.